# Redshift Copy command identity column is alternate value due to number of slices

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-insert, identity-column, csv-import

I am trying to achieve sequential incremental values in the identity column of Redshift while running copy command.

[Redshift-Identity column SEED-STEP behavior with COPY command](http://www.sqlhaven.com/amazon-redshift-identity-column-seed-step-behavior-with-copy-command/#comment-834) is an excellent article I followed to slowly move towards my target, but even after following the last step from the list and using the manifest file, I could only get (alternatively incrementing) 1,3,5,7... or 2,4,6,8... ID column values.

While creating table, I give that column as:

```
  bucketingid                             INT IDENTITY(1, 1) sortkey
```

I can understand the behavior is because my dc2.large single node cluster has 2 slices and hence I am getting the issue.

I am trying to upload a single csv file from S3 to redshift.

How can I achieve sequential incremental IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IDENTITY` column is **not guaranteed to produce consecutive values**. It guarantees to assign unique and monotonic values.

You can solve your problem with some sql once the data is loaded:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_with_consecutive_ids AS 
    SELECT 
       row_number() over (order by bucketingid) as consecutive_bucketingid, 
       *
    FROM my_table
```

## Some explaination why the problem occurs:

Since `COPY` performs distributed loading of your data, and each file is loaded by a node slice, loading only one file will be handled by a single slice. To be able to guarantee unique values while loading data in parallel by different slices, each of them is using an space of identities exclusive to itself (with 2 slices, one uses odd, and the other one even numbers).

Theoretically, you can have consecutive ids after loading the data if you split the file in two (*or whatever is the number of slices your cluster has*) and use both slices for loading (you'll need to use `MANIFEST` file), but it's highly impractical and you also make assumptions about your cluster size.

Same explaination from [`CREATE TABLE` manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html):

> IDENTITY(seed, step)
>
> ...
>   With a COPY operation, the data is loaded in parallel and distributed to the node slices. To be sure that the identity values are unique, Amazon Redshift skips a number of values when creating the identity values. As a result, identity values are unique and sequential, but not consecutive, and the order might not match the order in the source files.

Comment: Perfectly described. Appreciate it! I am aware of the staging to final table load with row_number() function. I was more into thinking of doing it in one shot and one table itself (reduces extra cost of loading another table just for this). Though maybe I am missing something, but you've made it quite clear for me. Thank you!